# Sharing a pic url to Pinterest from a flash banner ad

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, pinterest

Anyone know how I can get an expanding flash banner ad to share an image to Pinterest. It's not something from the banner, so I don't need to be able to upload anything, just send a link to a jpeg or png from the net. I'm coming up empty on flash code (AS3) relevant to Pinterest.

Comment: Looks like there is no official API for Pinterest. So even if it is possible, it's not an authorized way to do it. See https://help.pinterest.com/entries/21151603-i-m-a-developer-does-pinterest-have-a-public-api

Answer (score 0):

If you're trafficking with DoubleClick/Google there is a [Pinterest component](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/innovation/pinterest/en/index.html) you can use.

Otherwise you can follow their example and build your own [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) based proxy/bridge to the [Pinterest javascript](http://developers.pinterest.com/).